# MySQL foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

On other two tables, I have set foreign to d_desavanja->id field, but on this table, I can't.

How can I make it works?

```
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `d_des_kat` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `desavanje_id` ) REFERENCES  `desavanja`.`d_desavanja` (

`id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: 

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`desavanja/#sql-12f3_5af2e`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-12f3_5af2e_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`desavanje_id`) REFERENCES `d_desavanja` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: do a `show innodb status`. buried in the output will be a "last foreign key error" section with more details. usually the failure is due to a field-type mismatch of some sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a row in `d_des_kat` that fails the constraint. Check your data to make sure that all non-NULL `d_des_kat.desavanje_id` values match an existing `id` in `d_desavanja`.

The following query should show you the offending rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM d_des_kat
WHERE desavanje_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM d_desavanja)
```

Comment: i got this: http://i48.tinypic.com/29ld65k.png i just deleted these rows, and now i can add foreign key. thanks man

Comment: Sure thing. A foreign key enforces data integrity and will barf by design if you try to add a row that doesn't match the foreign table. A check is also done on the entire table when the key is added, which is what you saw here.